# Re-render the view - backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and i'm trying to re-render the contents of a view. I've put up the code in jsfiddle ...

http://jsfiddle.net/rzYLU/11/

So when user clicks re-render how can i remove the contents in the dom and show only the new items ?

Comment: i added this.$("#question-list").empty(); in addAll, is this the correct way of doing ?

Comment: thanks Matti..but is it the right way i'm not sure on this

Comment: I think with Backbone there is rarely a single right way. With a simple list, where you want to destroy all the previous elements I think it's the simplest thing to do.

Comment: For more complex scenarios with subviews, I found this blog post helpful:http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

Answer (score 4):

The safest thing to do is to keep track of your `QuestionView` instances inside your `AppView`. Then you can call `remove` on each `QuestionView` before adding the new ones; the [`remove` method is a](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove):

> Convenience function for removing the view from the DOM. Equivalent to calling `$(view.el).remove()`;

Views should provide their own `remove` implementation to unbind from non-DOM events and thus prevent zombies. The default simply removes the view's `el` from the DOM but if you do it right from the beginning, things will keep working nicely when your code inevitably changes.

First adjust your `QuestionView` to have a `remove` method to remove the event you've bound to the model:

```
var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    remove: function() {
        this.model.off('change', this.render);
        this.$el.remove();
    }
});
```

Then you'll need a couple adjustments to `AppView` to keep track of your `QuestionView`s:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        //...
        this.sub_views = [ ];
        //...
    },
    //...
    addOne: function(question) {
        var view = new QuestionView({
            model: question
        });
        this.sub_views.push(view); // <----------------------- Add this
        this.$("#question-list").append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.sub_views.length; ++i) // <--- And these three lines
            this.sub_views[i].remove();
        this.sub_views = [ ];
        Questions.each(this.addOne);
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FF9eG/

I've also updated your code to use [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) and [`off`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) instead of `bind` and `unbind` to match the new style. Newer versions of Backbone also have a cached version of `$(this.el)` in [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so I've updated the code to use that as well.